# My video is greenish, how do I correct it?

Tags: edit-mode, video

I guess automatic white balance was fooled by the background (garden through window), and now the people in the interior (yellowish light) look greenish. Is there a way to correct this white balance gone wrong?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to answer the question. Please upload a copy of your blend file, with relevant images packed, to a hosting site of your choice (or use [http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com] and post a link in your queston. It might also be useful to post one or more screenshots of the rendered scene.

Comment: Thanks brasshat, I'll do the next time. For this one, I think what @cegaton answered will be enough for a question this general :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load your clip on the compositor. Add a Color balance node and move the gamma in the opposite direction of the dominant hue of your scene. If your scene is green you want to make it more magenta.

[image]